# Powershell script to install app via choclatey but also check for choclatey is installed if not then it will install it

Tags: scripting, chocolatey

I have a script that partially works it will install the app for chocolatey but the ELSE command seems to fail I'm new to scripting so possibly missing something here.

```
$localprograms1 = choco list --localonly
$program1 = "3cx"

If(Test-Path -Path "$env:ProgramData\Chocolatey")
    {
        if ($localprograms1 -like "*$program1*")
            {
                choco upgrade $program1
            }
        else
            {
                choco install $program1 -y
            }
    }


Else 
    {
        Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))  
        {
            if ($localprograms1 -like "*$program1*")
                {
                    choco upgrade $program1
                }
            else
                {
                    choco install $program1 -y
                }
        }
    }
```

it seems to fail at the detection phase

Comment: I've given a script that should work (e.g. ensuring Chocolatey is available before running it in all scenarios), but if you provide the error you're getting when running your script folk will be able to help more easily.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things I'd suggest

Just from a personal perspective, I would suggest re-ordering this to make it run more seamlessly (and to be a little less repetitive!).

```
param(
    $Program = "3cx"
)

# First, make sure Chocolatey is available - if not, we install it!
if (-not (Get-Command choco -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
    Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072
    Invoke-Expression ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
    # Refresh the environment variables, to make sure choco is available
    Import-Module $env:ProgramData\chocolatey\helpers\chocolateyProfile.psm1
    Update-SessionEnvironment
}

# Having ensured Chocolatey is available, we can get our list of applications
# Using --limit-output (-r) and converting it from delimited format
$LocalPrograms = choco list --local-only --limit-output | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter '|' -Header Name, Version

# We can now check if the package is present, and can install / upgrade if not
if ($Program -in $LocalPrograms.Name) {
    choco upgrade $program1
} else {
    choco install $program1 --confirm
}
```

Having said that, `choco upgrade` will install or upgrade a program depending on it's presence, so you could replace everything after the installation of Chocolatey with `choco upgrade $program1 --confirm`.